# Too many NOT LIKE statements and WAAAAYYYY too many Wildcards

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

At my new job where I am NOT a SQL expert, I am trying to make a sql query in SSMS. I am trying to find all transactions that have 'insurance' or 'ins' in the Description field. So my code looks something like this (I have simplified/obfuscated it)

```
SELECT
a.Customer,
b.Amount,
c.Description

FROM
    table1 as a
    INNER JOIN table2 as b ON a.CustKey = b.AmtKey
    INNER JOIN table 3 as c ON a.CustKey = c.DescKey
    
WHERE
(
(c.Description LIKE '%insurance%' OR c.Description LIKE '%ins%')
AND
(
b.Description NOT LIKE '%domains%' AND b.Description NOT LIKE '%vitamins%' AND 
b.Description NOT LIKE '%Gainsville%' AND b.Description NOT LIKE '%circle k%'
b.Description NOT LIKE '%insane%'
))
```

So the Description field is an nvarchar(250) data type. It generally looks something like this
"ALFA MUTUAL INS   EFT PYMTS    PPD  SMITH JOHN"
or
"VISA/DEBIT-CARD      POS  STATE FARM  INSURANCE               8009566310     IL 8675309 0102"
but there are many other different ways that it looks. And some even have locations in the Description.

My problem is that '%ins%' is pulling in many results that are not relevant. For example, it will pull in all transactions that were made at a business called "Insane Cookies". So I add NOT LIKE '%insane%'. But than it will include ALL transactions that were made by John Smith Atkins who purchased insurance but also made purchases at Circle K gas stations. I do NOT want to exclude the 'insurance' purchases, but I do want to exclude his gas station purchases. So I add NOT LIKE '%circle k%'. This has made me create a very long list of NOT LIKE statements (about 48 NOT LIKE '%value%' statements)

Because the Description field is essentially a string, I cannot just use 'ins' or 'insurance'. I have to use the wildcard characters. **My query actually works but** I have sooooo many NOT LIKE statements and each NOT LIKE statements has two wildcard characters that it is bogging down the system. They (DBAs) are instructing me to modify my query. I knew this would happen. I tried to ask for help because so many NOT LIKE statements + wildcards = poor performance, but "apparently" everyone who could help is too busy. So I'm here.

This is my first time posting/asking for help on here. So I apologize if I overstated or understated my predicament. Feel free to ask and I will provide clarification. I'd appreciate ANY help.

TLDR: what are alternatives methods to a long list of NOT LIKE + wildcards?

Edit: change "or" in NOT LIKE area to "and". I have it as "and" in my query.

Comment: You can perhaps do something like: select * from yourtable where ' ' + Description + ' ' LIKE '% ins %' or  ' ' + Description + ' ' like '% insurance %'  . this will at least do a word match for your keywords

Comment: you could also checkout full text indexes which allows more powerful word processing

Comment: Without some clear sample data and expected results it's not easy to be specific, try using `charindex`. Any data you expect to filter or search on should be properly normalised or you have issues like you are having.

Comment: `not like "AAA" or not like "BBB" ...` doesn't make any sense because one of those `not like` will always be true and the query will return all rows

Comment: @derpirscher, you are exactly correct. They were supposed to be "and" instead of "or". I have edited my post to reflect that. Thank you.

Comment: Furthermore also `x like "%insurance%" or x like "%ins%"` doesn't make too much sense either, because the prior implies the latter

Comment: @Stu Yes, the lack of normalization in my company's databases is mind blowing. I appreciate that I'm the new kid on the block who doesn't have alot of data experience under my belt, but even I know that it is wrong. And I completely agree that is contributing to the current problem I have. Otherwise, this would be a perfect opportunity for charindex!

Comment: @derprischer, I understand what you mean, but it is necessary. (just throwing numbers out there) only 40% actually use "insurance" in the Description field. Otherwise, it's some combination of "ins" (IE "INSPREM", "CK4INS", "INS PYMT", "INSUR", "INSPAYMENT", and so on). But feel free to correct me if I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: @siggemannen that's an interesting suggestion. I'll take a look into indexes. I don't know if my bosses will allow me to create one, but worst case scenario, I can learn something I can use somewhere else. Thank you.

Comment: you could create a table with insurance keywords as well as negative keywords and then join on this table and do a like / not like. The performance will likely suck, but maybe better than nothing, and once you're done, you should create a proper column to set the insurance flag once and for all

Comment: lookup "sql trigram wildcard search" on your favorite search engine and see if it might help out your case.

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you just use `like "%ins%` it will also cover all unstances of `%insurance%`

Comment: @derpisher is unstance a new thing like NOT an instance, most likely it is a typo (LOL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing out text to get what you're after will never be 100% correct.  If someone enters `INS` meaning `Immigration & Naturalization Services` you're going to get a false positive you can't ever manage. The best you can do is "Default" an option; but rely on user intervention to set a flag/value to know it's insurance related.

Knowing this there may be a way to make your query more performant using SET based processing; avoiding a Not like.

Essentially get all the possible INS records in a set; then exclude all the ones that match your not like criteria but using a like instead.

In a perfect world you'd have some sort of record indicator to indicate this was insurance related and key off it instead.  Are you sure there's not another way to identify insurance related records besides scraping text?

```
-- Get Set of data which we think is "Insurance" related

SELECT
a.Customer,
b.Amount,
c.Description
FROM table1 as a
INNER JOIN table2 as b ON a.CustKey = b.AmtKey
INNER JOIN table 3 as c ON a.CustKey = c.DescKey
WHERE (c.Description LIKE '%insurance%' 
   OR c.Description LIKE '%ins%')   --this is inclusive of the former so just use it.

EXCEPT  --aka MINUS

--Now exclude these similar records containing descriptions we want to ignore. 
-- (false positives) Note: like is generally faster than "not like"   so by treating 
-- these as data sets and excluding one from the other, you may see a performance gain.  
-- But you'll always have false positives in your results since you can't have a list 
-- that will always exclude EVERY variant of ins.  Your best bet is to find or maintain 
-- a field/table where someone controls this association. For example, you're 100% stuck if someone puts in INS (meaning Immigration & Naturalization Services'

SELECT
a.Customer,
b.Amount,
c.Description
FROM table1 as a
INNER JOIN table2 as b ON a.CustKey = b.AmtKey
INNER JOIN table 3 as c ON a.CustKey = c.DescKey
WHERE (b.Description LIKE '%domains%' 
  OR b.Description LIKE '%vitamins%' 
  OR b.Description LIKE '%Gainsville%' 
  OR b.Description LIKE '%circle k%' 
  OR b.Description LIKE '%insane%')
```

Alternatively you could add a [computed (persisted?) column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns?view=sql-server-ver16) to the database which evaluates the text for the desired string excluding the undesired strings in a case expression pushing the analysis/performance to the save of a record vs the read.  This field would simply contain a 1 if insurance related 0 if not and have an evaluation using a case expression something like:

```
where description like '%INS%' 
  and (Description not like '%...%' 
    or Description not like '%....%'...) 
 then 1 else 0 end
```

but again no matter what, you'll never hit 100% success.

Comment: In the second query, `AND`s should be `OR`s.

Comment: Good catch that.

Comment: The `EXCEPT` logic is great, but the list would need to be appended to forever with new words, that is still a fundamental problem, see point 2. of my answer, and finally I think that point 1. is the way to go.

Comment: the problem with spaces is if it's at the first or last word like 'Insurance word Sales' or 'My house needs Insurance'  Not all will have spaces.  I go back to there's no perfect solution for this without manual intervention or a true field indicating it's insurance related.  If we're shooting for 100% accuracy; IMO it's not achievable given the rules thus far.  The best we can do is provide a "Default Guess"

Comment: But that is why the orginial value needs spaces on both ends - it is in my solution and previously suggested by comment. This is (one) usual word boundary handling.

Comment: Ah... I missed the fact you were suggesting altering "Description"  to pad spaces on either end.  negates index use; but %word% can't use an index anyway soo... no harm I guess

Comment: Everyone really helped and I greatly appreciate it. The DBAs at my company actually made a temp table for me (I wasn't anticipating that). And from there, I was able to use the EXCEPT as shown by @xQbert which REALLY helped. I think it's fair to say that this was a difficult unique problem due to the Description string. "ins" could be like "Prem INS 234598" in another it might be "8671 pymtinschk". Hopefully, I will be able to create some type of "not these words" list. But really ya'll helped out alot and I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Last comment: there's materialized views which could be used for this as well and they can get updated as data changes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-materialized-view-as-select-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest  if the issue is the load at select; this will push the load to system updates instead adding overhead for new/changed data; but reducing load at read time since the data is replicated to a view.

Comment: @jash45357 But you didn't listen to my warning though: your "not these words" list will grow forever. Avoiding that would be more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the `NOT LIKE` list, you need to think about word boundaries, as @siggemannen also pointed out:

1. If you would want to find only the words "insurance" and "ins", and not any abbreviation of "insurance":
   You could just put spaces around these words to eliminate false matches, and also around the original values not to exclude when they are the first or last words:
   `('`*[space]*`' + c.Description + '`*[space]*`' LIKE '%`*[space]*`insurance`*[space]*`%' OR '`*[space]*`' + c.Description + '`*[space]*`' LIKE '%`*[space]*`ins`*[space]*`%')`
   A more complicated but also potentially more performant way of expressing the equivalent is:
   `(c.Description LIKE 'insurance`*[space]*`%' OR c.Description LIKE 'ins`*[space]*`%' OR '`*[space]*`' + c.Description + '`*[space]*`' LIKE '%`*[space]*`insurance`*[space]*`%' OR '`*[space]*`' + c.Description + '`*[space]*`' LIKE '%`*[space]*`ins`*[space]*`%')`
2. If you want any abbreviation of "insurance":
   First, regarding `c.Description LIKE '%insurance%' OR c.Description LIKE '%ins%'` - as it is `OR`, the first is redundant, as `insurance` contains `ins`. Therefore `ins` remains, but no abbreviation can contain any character before this word, so there should be a space:
   `'`*[space]*`' + c.Description LIKE '%`*[space]*`ins%'`
   a potentially more performant equivalent is
   `c.Description LIKE 'ins%' OR '`*[space]*`' + c.Description LIKE '%`*[space]*`ins%'`.
   This doesn't eliminate all `NOT LIKE`s, but many like "domains" or "Gainsville" will go away and only "insane" and the likes remain - **however this approach should be avoided, as there are a ton of other words that you will have to exclude in the future. It is more reliable to include ALL possible abbreviations in point 1, as there are less variants.**